# Flutter pod: An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, cocoapods, podfile

The problem is that when I run a flutter app after having installed a plugin (firebase_core in this case) I get an error:

> An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the
> Podfile.
>
> undefined local variable or method `continue' for
> #<Pod::Podfile:0x00000001099e67b8 @defined_in_file=#Pathname:/Volumes/Coding-IT/Coding/Projects/flutter_37hours/ios/Podfile,
> @internal_hash={},
> @root_target_definitions=[#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition
> label=Pods>],
> @current_target_definition=#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition
> label=Pods>, @post_install_callback=#<Proc:0x0000000109a07e40
> /Volumes/Coding-IT/Coding/Projects/flutter_37hours/ios/Podfile:37>,
> @installation_options=#<Pod::Installer::InstallationOptions:0x0000000109ab6eb8
> @clean=true, @deduplicate_targets=true, @deterministic_uuids=true,
> @integrate_targets=true, @lock_pod_sources=true,
> @warn_for_multiple_pod_sources=true,
> @warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo=true,
> @share_schemes_for_development_pods=false,
> @disable_input_output_paths=false, @preserve_pod_file_structure=false,
> @generate_multiple_pod_projects=false,
> @incremental_installation=false, @skip_pods_project_generation=false>>
>
> ```
>   continue if xcframework_file.start_with?(".") # Hidden file, possibly on external disk.
> ```

The problem appears to be with the continue word, but I don't know exactly why this is happening and how to solve the problem :(
I've tried reinstalling cocoapods multiple times, from homebrew and from rubygems, I tried flutter clean, I tried reinstalling ruby and changing versions. No luck. Hope someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into this too. It seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104118

But it's closed the fix seems to be merged with flutter master branch. Idk! Might need to wait for next flutter update.

edit - I just tried this on beta channel and pod install completed. So you can wait till it's on stable or switch channels to run iOS. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is facing this same issue,

1. Check ruby installation (use above ruby 3.1.3p185)
2. Check coco-pads (10.1.2 above)
3. Delete and Redownload your entire flutter sdk

move to iOS folder, run flutter pre cache, then pod install

For ruby >> brew install rbenv 3.1.3 (or use any version you want)

```
which ruby >>> (To confirm installation path on mac /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby)

sudo gem install bundler >>> (needed for cocopoads)
```

For cocopoads>>

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.3
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.3
```

Delete Flutter SDK, and redownload to the same path it existed before.

Then on your project, move to your ios folder and run

```
flutter precache --ios
cd ../ (to move back)
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install --verbose
```